# Running webpack on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, webpack

I have a project which uses webpack. To run webpack, I first installed node (v. 6.9.1) and npm (v. 3.10.8), then used `sudo npm install webpack -g` to install webpack globally. When I try to run webpack in the project, it says the following error:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/myproj/webpack.config.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I searched a lot online, and the best suggestion was to install it locally. I tried to install it locally, but then I got this error:

```
npm ERR! not a package /path/to/myproj/webpack
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /path/to/myproj/webpack
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "webpack"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path /var/folders/zk/vhg127bn2b1g2vg4mfb941yr0000gn/T/npm-14256-797b3412/unpack-5c7f7eb6/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/zk/vhg127bn2b1g2vg4mfb941yr0000gn/T/npm-14256-797b3412/unpack-5c7f7eb6/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/zk/vhg127bn2b1g2vg4mfb941yr0000gn/T/npm-14256-797b3412/unpack-5c7f7eb6/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /path/to/myproj/npm-debug.log
```

So I thought maybe I have to uninstall webpack first. I did so using `sudo npm remove webpack -g`, and tried to install it locally, but still the same error. This time even installing it globally would generate the same error. So I could not install webpack unless I reinstalled node.

So why originally the webpack package was not found? how I can install it to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: You also need webpack installed in the project as well if you are using `require('webpack')` in your `webpack.config.js`. It should be saved as a dev dependency in your `package.json`.

Comment: Yes, the webpack.config.js has `require('webpack')`, but still when I try to install webpack locally, it tells me it cannot do so because 'no such file or directory'! There is a list of requirements in the package.json file of the project, and I can install all of them locally (`autoprefixer`, `css-loader`, etc.), but when it comes to webpack, it fails. Clearly it's something with the project setting, but there is no clue as how to solve it!

Comment: `npm remove` is not a valid npm command from what I can see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/) Try `npm uninstall webpack -g` instead